# Notify html to update itself (Sending signals to HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Say that I Have a div with a table in it. I would like to remotely notify the html page that the table has been updated with another row in it. Is this even possible in Html?

I will only do this for testing purpose and will view the site on the same computer that I send the notification from so thats no "security" issue that we are dealing with here.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="name">Harry</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to notify the Html site to update the div with `id="test"` with the new table whitout the user pressing anything in the html site. I.E from another place on the site execute a function that will update the div in real time when notified.

```
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="name">Harry</td>
            <td class="name">Flynn</td>
            <td class="name">Niklas</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I know that this is a strange question and it's rather unspecific, I apologize for that. What I want to do is to have a SQL database and as soon as the database is updated then it should notify the html page to update itself, but as I said I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Check out a COMET solution like Meteor http://meteor.com/ or DerbyJS: http://derbyjs.com/ . Both will offer you a solution that you need - as soon as the database is updated, the front end is updated. However (for Meteor), you will need to use MongoDB as opposed to a traditional RDBMS - unless you use a script like this one for Meteor - http://www.fastcolabs.com/3007015/how-use-mysql-meteor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "notify" HTML page directly (i.e. "push"), however what you can do is run a javascript on the page at predetermined intervals, say, every 10 seconds, or whatever is appropriate for your, to poll the server-side for any new data and update the HTML.  You'd have something like

```
var interval = setInterval(function() { updateTestData(); }, 10000);

function upateTestData() {
    //use ajax to poll for new data and update DOM tree
}
```

Or you can only request to update again if necessary:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() { updateTestData(); }, 10000);

function upateTestData() {
    //use ajax to poll for new data and update DOM tree
    ...
    if(need to refresh again after some time) {
        timer = setTimeout(function() { updateTestData(); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Fair enough.  I personally don't like `setInterval` anyway and prefer `setTimeout` instead.  However I showed it for simplicity in this case.  I updated the answer with `setTimeout` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJs or KnockoutJs which are two javascript frameworks that update dom elements automatically according to changes in the viewmodel.

1. you send data to the server or sql server.
2. you return the updated data to the html page where the viewmodel exists.
3. viewmodel constructor(knockout or angularJs) gets the updated data and updates the dom elements according to the bindings it has.

Answer (score 0):

You do this with a technology called Ajax.

What you have to do is to set a timeout every certain amount of time, and send a query to the server using ajax and checking if there are more rows to add in the table.

There are plenty of Ajax-related tutorials on the internet, this website has one, for example: http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: I just added an example of a website containing Ajax-related tutorials. w3schools is pretty good for beginners, despite the possible flaws it might have.

Answer (score 0):

The `websockets` would be the final solution, but a bit complex to implement in your case. Furthermore only last generation of browsers support it.

You should create a setInterval function in your HTML page, and check a timestamp stored in database for example to know if your page is up to date or not.

For example :

In your HTML page :

```
var now = new Date();
var timestamp = now.getTime();

setInterval(function(){
    $.post('retrieveLastTimestamp.php',{},function(data){
        if(intval(data) > timestamp)
        {
            //The page is no longer up to date
            document.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
},5000);

//Call this function to update the last timestamp dta of your page after row insertion
function updateTimestamp()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var timestamp = now.getTime();
    $.post('updateTimestamp.php',{timestamp : timestamp },function(data){
        alert('timestamp update done');
    });
}
```

retrieveLastTimestamp.php

```
<?php 
    //SQL request to retrieve the last refresh timestamp
    echo timestamp;
?>
```

updateTimestamp.php

```
<?php 
    //SQL request updtae the last timestamp
    $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @aleks-g explained, you cannot push information to html.

However, there are plenty of free or cheap push services which you might use. They come with simple javascript configuration, and the idea is that server send some signal and a javascript listener is fired when this signal is sent.
In this way you can have a real-time behavior without the need to fire excessive ajax calls.

You can implement it using [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), or use some existing service as [Pusher](https://pusher.com/).